# Sum equal data in DataTable and pass them to a new DataTable C #

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM XXXXX
```

What I recover I keep it in a `DataTable`, let's say that this `DataTable` looks like this (the reflection of the table):

```
code       description     amount     unit    prize
----------------------------------------------------
0001          papaya        100,5      KG      75
0002          mango          50        KG      50
0001          papaya        200,5      KG      75
```

How can I go through the DataTable and sum all the "Amounts" if they have the same code and pass it to a new datatable like this?

```
code        description          amount     unit    prize
----------------------------------------------------------
0001          papaya               301      KG         75
0002          mango                 50      KG         50
```

I tried something like this, but I kinda lost (I think isn't the correct way to do this):

```
var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>("code") into g
            select new 
                   {
                        cod_parte = g.Key,
                        descripcion = g.First().GetChildRows("descripcion").ToString(),
                        cantidad = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("cantidad")),
                        unidad = g.First().GetChildRows("unidad").ToString(),
                        precio = Convert.ToDouble(g.First().GetChildRows("precio"))
                   };

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Prize", typeof(double));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add("0001", "papaya", "100", "KG", 75);
        table.Rows.Add("0002", "mango", "50", "KG", 50);
        table.Rows.Add("0001", "papaya", "200", "KG", 75);

        var rows = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Code")).Select(g =>
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();

            row["Code"] = g.Key;
            row["Description"] = row.Field<string>("Description");
            row["Amount"] = g.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("Amount"));
            row["Unit"] = row.Field<string>("Unit");
            row["Prize"] = row.Field<double?>("Prize") == null ? 0 : row.Field<double>("Prize");
            return row;
        }).CopyToDataTable();

        foreach (var data1 in rows.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data1.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: any recomedations with this error: Cannot set Column `prize` to be null. Please use DBNull instead.' Prize is a double, idk its this a problem?

Comment: I only to change the `row` with `g` cuz all the row with row were empty, thanx

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved using System.Linq

Using your data table example above you should first group by the code and then select a new object with the key and the sum for each element in the grouping.

This can be achieved using the below code

```
// Fill our list
var list = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {Code = 1, Price = 2},
    new Item {Code = 2, Price = 2},
    new Item {Code = 1, Price = 2}
};

// Perform LINQ
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Code).Select(x => new
{
    Code = x.Key,
    Sum = x.Sum(z => z.Price)
}).ToList();
```

Or to follow your data table examples (My Spanish is not 100%)

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("code")).Select(x => new
{
    cod_parte = x.Key,
    cantidad = x.Sum(z => z.Field<int>("cantidad")),
}).ToList();
```